# Powershell script works when remoted in, but not as Azure startup task

Tags: powershell, azure, command-line, permissions, zip

I have an powershell script saved in a `.cmd` file that downloads a file from the web and then unzips it.  My azure web role executes it upon startup.  This is the script:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c $(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('URL.zip', 'FILE.zip') ;
 (New-Object -com shell.application).namespace('c:\FOLDER').Copyhere((New-Object -com shell.application).namespace('FILE.zip').items())
```

When I run the script via Azure startup tasks:
The first part of the script works.  The file is downloaded.  The second part of the script which unzips does not run.

When I run the script via the command line when remoted into the VM:
The entire script runs.

I therefore know this is not a syntax error.  The only difference I can think of between the two cases above is a permissions issue.  But, I am running powershell with -ExecutionPolicy set to Bypass, which is the highest permission level.  Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what the line from your service configuration that runs the startup task looks like?

Comment: Were u able to find the problem? I'm having a similar issue, I run a script to unzip files and it works when I run the process manually on the server but when the automatic process runs it does not run, it doesn't even throw an exception, it simply doesn't unzip my files

Comment: @Jupaol, I'm fairly certain it's a permission level you can't bypass.  My solution was to have the startup script kick off a console app that does the unzipping for me.  That works.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change the command so that the output of the command is dumped into a file. Something like this should work

```
<YOUR_COMMAND> > out.log 2> err.log
```

Run the task again and checkout the output in the logs.

Also, you are using relative paths rather than absolute ones. The scheduled task probably run with the windows system folder as its working directory, so you may be getting a permissions error from that. Try using an absolute path to a directory you created.